# may I use ios Framework CallKit to show called name in iPhone built-in phone aap?

Tags: ios, callkit, call-directory-extension

I know iOS has a Framework CallKit with Call Directory App Extension that can show caller name when phone is coming, but I want to know if the built-in phone app can show the name? does anyone explain to me?

Comment: https://github.com/paulw11/CallKitTutorial

Comment: Thanks a lot and answer me.